# What is a term for "good to go"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, english-to-japanese

I want to verify if 行ってもいい is the correct term, or if another word(s) can be used.

Comment: よし、準備できた is what i found to be the closest. As good to go is an expression it might not have a direct translation

Comment: as i'm just a beginner, my answers may not always be spot on and i could perhaps lead you to a wrong conclusion, so I am just giving my 2 cents here until someone more capable comes with the correct answer :)

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Want to practice in the Nihongo Benkyou chat room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idiomatic way of saying "good to go" is

> 準備万端（です）

準備 (also 用意) means "preparations".

Another standard way would be

> 準備でき（まし）た　or
>   用意でき（まし）た

---

行ってもいい could be misunderstood as asking "may I go?". 行く may indeed be used in this context for "are you good/ready to go?" as 「（もう）行けますか」. However, I *don't* think 「行ってもいいです（よ）」 would be a natural way of saying "I'm good to go".

Comment: Even if you try to use *go* literally, as in "Are you ready to go to the beach? Yes, I am *good to go*.", it still means you are prepared to go. Whether you actually go to the beach is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

(Really wanted to add this in the comment but don't have enough reputation)

「準備できた」 is a normal expression in this case. It could mean many things including not just "good to go" but also "ready for a trip", "ready for delivery".

Comment: It's the case of an expression which there's no direct translation probably, so we have to take something that is closer and at times will have different meanings, I guess